# How to augment wired headphones with a Bluetooth transmitter / receiver?

Tags: headphones, wireless

I have a set of Sony MDR-5 headphones that sound great, but I'd like to hook them up to my receiver with a wireless audio system. 
My plan is to connect a Bluetooth receiver to the headphones' jack cable and a Bluetooth transmitter to the amplifier.

Has anyone done something like this before? I was researching on Amazon for a Bluetooth system, but not I'm sure what I really need.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do. You want to use your Sony headphones as wireless?

Comment: Yeah, so I would have a Bluetooth device (transmitter) hooked up to the headphone jack of my receiver and plug my headphones  up to the receiving device.

Answer (score 1):

Through various components I have come up with a  solution. I have found a [Bluetooth transmitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008GVETNE) that I can connect to my receiver's phone jack (I will need to use a 1/8" to 1/4" stereo adapter) and a [Bluetooth receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009G48ZE4) to connect my headphone to. If you are familiar with the Sonly MDR-5 headphones they have a screw on 1/4" adapter. So you can use a 1/4" input or 1/8"

Comment: link is broken. I'm also interested in connecting two amplifiers (one gets music from aux input and streams via bluetooth to another amplifier which gets music from bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

I have done half of this before.  The biggest trick is to make sure that there are good DAC / ADCs in the devices.  If the conversion from analog to digital or back again isn't very good, then the system isn't going to work well.

I used to use a bluetooth DAC for my headphones because the DAC in my phone itself wasn't very good.  I don't remember the brand, but it worked quite well in improving the sound I got out of my Shure 535s.